# Adding greek character and asterisk (*) to axis title

Tags: r, label

I want to add a greek character to the x-axis of my histogram plot in R.
I can write the greek character alone or with the hat, but the problem is that I need this character to be come with a hat and asterisk (*) together. More specifically, I want the something like hat(phi^*). Here is what I have done:

```
x = rnorm(1000)
hist( x, nclass = 100, cex.lab=1.5, xlab = expression(hat(phi^*)), 
ylab="Frequency", main="", cex.axis=1.5 )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `ggplot2` instead of base R. You can then use `latex2exp::TeX` to use (some) LaTeX expressions in the axes labels.

```
set.seed(2018)
x = rnorm(1000)

library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

ggplot(data.frame(x = x), aes(x)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 100) +
    theme_minimal() +
    xlab(TeX("$\\widehat{\\phi^*}$"))
```

[image]

You need to escape the backslashes with an extra backslash and wrap math expressions inside `$` delimiters (just as in regular LaTeX inline math). I used `\widehat{}`, but you can also use `hat{}` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the best looking solution that I found:

```
hist( x, nclass = 100, cex.lab=1.5, xlab = expression(hat(phi)~"*"), 
      ylab="Frequency", main="", cex.axis=1.5 )
```

[image]

---

To get the star under the hat, I don't know of any nice looking solution with base plot functions. I think @Maurits Evers' method is the best compromise between complexity and prettiness of the result.

But here is anyway a more "advanced" (and maybe a little bit over the top, but well...) solution. It is based on this blog post: http://iltabiai.github.io/tips/latex/2015/09/15/latex-tikzdevice-r.html

To make it work, you will need to install the `tikzDevice` package.

First, load the packages and create the data-set.

```
library(tikzDevice)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))
```

Then create a TeX file that will contain the "translation" of your R plot in "tikz" language.

```
tikz(file = "plot_test.tex", width = 5, height = 5, standAlone = TRUE)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="white") + theme_bw() +
  labs( x = "$\\widehat{\\phi^*}$")
dev.off()
```

Then, you can either directly copy or call the LaTeX code into your own LaTeX document (then the `standAlone=TRUE` argument is not necessary), or you can use these two very useful function to generate a pdf version and see the result.

```
tools::texi2dvi("plot_test.tex", pdf=TRUE)
system(paste(getOption('pdfviewer'), "plot_test.pdf"))
```

[image: TikZ result]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I would like the * to be under the hat.

Comment: Maybe `expression(hat(phi^'*'))` ?